# Get a specific words from a specific line from a text file in NetBSD

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

How does one proceed to extract member names from a list like the one below and output them to a new file?

```
Group-name supernatural 
Members admin, Admin1, John, sam, dean 
Group-id 405
```

expected out-put of newfile.txt :

```
admin
Admin1
John
sam
dean
```

Comment: It is so far very unclear what your expected output is. What do you want to appear in the new file? Each name in its own line? Should the word 'Members' appear? Edit your quesion and include an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^Members/ { for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) { sub(",$", "", $i); print $i } }' file
admin
Admin1
John
sam
dean
```

This uses `awk` to look for any line that starts with the string `Members`.  When such a line is found, it iterates over the whitespace-delimited fields of that line, from the second field onwards. Each field has its trailing comma removed (if one exists) before it's printed on its own line.

Redirect the output to a new file if you wish to save it, using

```
awk ...as above... file >newfile
```

---

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '/^Members[[:blank:]]*/{ s///; s/,[[:blank:]]*/,/g; y/,/\n/; p; }' file
admin
Admin1
John
sam
dean
```

This locates the lines starting with the string `Members` and then deletes this string and any blanks (tabs or spaces) following it. It then removes the blanks after any comma in the remainder of the line and changes the commas into newlines before printing the resulting list.

With GNU `sed`, you could combine

```
s/,[[:blank:]]*/,/g; y/,/\n/; p;
```

into

```
s/,[[:blank:]]*/\n/gp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just try with below command combination of awk and sed

```
awk '/^Members/{$1=" ";print $0}' filename |sed "s/,/\n/g"| sed -r "s/^\s+//g"
```

output

```
admin
Admin1
John
sam
dean
```

Comment: I'm uncertain whether `sed` on NetBSD is able to substitute in a newline like that. GNU `sed` would be able to, though.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with python and it worked fine

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import subprocess
k=re.compile(r'^Members')
y=open('u.txt','r')
for  i in y:
        if re.search(k,i):
            k=re.sub("Members"," ",i)
            print re.sub(",","\n",k).strip()
praveen@praveen:~$
```

output

```
admin
 Admin1
 John
 sam
 dean
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for member in $(cat /tmp/yourfile.txt | grep Members | cut -d' ' -f2-); do 
          echo $member | cut -d, -f1  
 done
```

Results:

```
admin
Admin1
John
sam
dean
```

And it works if you have more than one 'Members' line in the file.